# OpenShift: Connecting to JBoss EAP 6 management (SSH tunneling?)

Tags: command-line-interface, jboss, openshift-online-2

I'm trying to connect to JBoss EAP 6 instance management on OpenShift.

Connecting directly doesn't work (firewall), so I want to set up a SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -L 10999:localhost:9999 683...@web-ozcz.rhcloud.com
```

And then

```
jboss-eap-6.1/bin/jboss-cli.sh --gui --controller=localhost:10999
```

But on the serverside, I get this:

```
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

**How can I connect to the management CLI?**
**How to set up the system to allow SSH tunnel?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this forum post [JBoss AS7 management in OpenShift?](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/jboss-as7-management-in-openshift) in OpenShift site the management port is not accessible without first setting up port forwarding within OpenShift:

> The JBoss management console has been disabled on the JBoss cartridge
>   embedded in OpenShift.
>
> [...]
>
> The management console is bound to an
>   internal port (9990). To access the JBoss management console, you can
>   use port forwarding:
>
> ```
> > rhc port-forward jbosseap
> Checking available ports ... done
> Forwarding ports ...
>
>
> To connect to a service running on OpenShift, use the Local address
>
> Service Local               OpenShift
> ------- -------------- ---- ---------------
> java    127.0.0.1:3528  =>  127.6.85.1:3528
> java    127.0.0.1:4447  =>  127.6.85.1:4447
> java    127.0.0.1:5445  =>  127.6.85.1:5445
> java    127.0.0.1:8080  =>  127.6.85.1:8080
> java    127.0.0.1:9990  =>  127.6.85.1:9990
> java    127.0.0.1:9999  =>  127.6.85.1:9999
>
> Press CTRL-C to terminate port forwarding
> ```
>
> While that is running, use a local browser to hit:
>   `http://127.0.0.1:9990/console/App.html`
>
> For more details about port forwarding, please refer to:
>   https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift